# What is the best practice to use asserts in Ruby, but not as part of unit tests?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, assertions, rake-task

I want to use an assert to raise an error within a rake task.

```
the_index = items.index(some_item)
assert_not_nil the_index, "Lookup failed for the following item: " + some_item
```

I get `undefined method assert_not_nil`. Can I include the assertions file in my rake task? How?

Is this a best practice, or is there a better way to do it?

Working in Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Unit testing and exception handling are two very different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in `Array#fetch` method that acts like `#[]` but raises an IndexError instead of returning nil when the element is not found. (The same applies for Hash.) I always use the first one if I don't expect the collection to exclude an element.

```
a = [:foo, :bar]
a.fetch(0)   #=> :foo
a[4]         #=> nil
a.fetch(4)   #=> IndexError: index 4 outside of array bounds: -2...2
```

And for the other cases raise exceptions yourself like Bramha Ghosh suggests:

```
raise "I don't expect this to be nil!" if element.nil?
```

However, you shouldn't be doing this often, only if you know that your code will fail far away making debugging painful.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use assertions wherever you want.

```
require "minitest/unit"
include MiniTest::Assertions # all assertions are in this module
refute_nil @ivar, "An instance variable should not be nil here!"
```

But why would you do that? Raise meaningful exceptions yourself instead.

Answer (score 1):

is there a special reason you want to use an assert?

Why not

```
raise IndexError, "Lookup failed for the following item: #{some_item}" unless items.include? some_item
```